# Confusion about choosing an Euclidean world sheet metric in String Theory path integral

Tags: metric-tensor, string-theory, wick-rotation

When it comes to construct a well-defined path integral for the Polyakov action in Bosonic String Theory, most authors assume that the world sheet metric $g$ is Riemannian (i.e. it has Euclidean signature). However, the target space is generally taken to be a Lorentzian manifold, such as Minkowski space. The constraint imposed over $g$ is that it must be conformal to the metric induced both by the target space (Lorentzian) metric and the embedding $X$. This is not forbidden, but if the pullback happens to be Riemannian, we lose the usual view of a string propagating in a timelike direction in spacetime. How to solve this conceptual problem?

Comment: Polchinski says "It has been shown by explicit calculation that [Minkowski and Euclidean path integrals for the worldsheet] define the same amplitudes, respectively in the light-cone and conformal gauges."